# Arraylist objects database records cleanup

Tags: c#, .net, database, ado.net

I have a table called Vendors for example. I also created a class called Vendor so that I can fill a ListView with Vendor Objects. Let's say that that table contains two columns ( Name and Phone) therefore my class Vendor contains those two string properties. If I have an ArrayList of Vendor objects and I wish to delete does vendors in the database how could I do this without building the query?

I am building a class to fill the listview dynamically based on whatever query I pass to the constructor of that class. The class then creates a SqlDataReader object to loop through the records. depending on how many columns there are they will dynamically be added to the listview. The only problem is that when I want to delete the selected rows for example (selected rows will be a collection of vendor objects if referred to the above example) sometimes I get errors building the query. sometimes some of the columns are null and I do not know in advance which column will be the primary key. Moreover the class vendors gets constructed dynamically based on the result from the query. So everything is great. I know I can create a linqToSqlClass or maybe bind it to a dataset. It will be nice if I do not have to modify this class. Maybe when I am looping through the records there is some way of finding the primary key of that row.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using SQL 2008 you could create a procedure that accepts a [Table-Valued parameter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb675163.aspx).

Another option is to convert your ArrayList to an XML string and pass that to a stored procedure works with SQL 2000 and greater

Comment: Thanks, those are great solutions. I forgot to mention that I am building a library of classes that I need a lot for work. That is the reason why I am not creating stored procedures nor LinqToSql classes by just draging desired tables in VisualStudio. I want to be able to use this classes without having to create all those things. I will be working constructing that query that is the only thing my class is missing.

Answer (score 0):

I pass the primary key table name to the constructor of that class and I made that field a required parameter. That way I can build the query more easy. I knew I can do this at the beginning I am just trying to avoid having to pass extra parameters to the class if somehow I can prevent that. LinqToSQLdata classes in visual studio enable you to do that.